# MySQL full text search allow plurals of words but not words of any length

Tags: mysql

I'm doing fulltext search in MySQL

I want to be able to search if a word is plural (in a simple way, not worried about all edge cases).

However, this approach I'm doing will return words that are any length.

For example, I want to search for "Mary" or "Mary's", but this approach is also returning "Maryland".

How should I change this to return only plurals of words (simple "s" case, not worried about other edge cases), and not many characters on the end of the string.

I want to return "Mary", "Marys", or "Mary's", but not "Maryland"

```
SELECT *
       FROM newssitestwo 
       WHERE (MATCH(snippet, name) AGAINST("Mary*" IN BOOLEAN MODE))
       ORDER BY datePublished DESC
       LIMIT 300
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do a separated `WHERE` `OR` with a `CONCAT`.

```
WHERE (
    MATCH(snippet, name) 
    AGAINST("Mary" IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
OR 
    MATCH(snippet, name) 
    AGAINST(CONCAT("Mary", "s") IN BOOLEAN MODE)
OR 
    MATCH(snippet, name) 
    AGAINST(CONCAT("Mary", "'s") IN BOOLEAN MODE)
)
```

You could aslo use it this way:

```
WHERE MATCH (snippet, name) 
  AGAINST ("Mary" "Marys" "Mary's" IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Comment: This will work, however, it may impact query speed because it's using many OR statements